Using material2 and material3 in my Mobile app
(Issue resolved, all I had to do was to import the right version of material in my dependencies and sync it, then I had to import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.*
I have a mobile app i am developing using kotlin. i want to use icons to change the visibility of password on my login page. the app is using material3 but the icons that i want are in material2.

should i just downgrade my material?
is it possible to use material2 and material3 at the same time?

i tried changing my build.gradle.kts dependencies to use material2.
implementation(libs.androidx.material3) --> implementation(libs.androidx.material2)
however, i found errors popping up
Unresolved reference to version catalog
Unresolved reference: material2

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Do not downgrade to Material 2.
Although possible, you should also not mix Material 2 and Material 3 composables. If you just want to use the Material 2 icons, however, that is possible by adding the dependency androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended (if you use the extended variant make sure your release build uses proguard to remove unnecessary code, this dependency will otherwise drastically bloat the size of your app). Then you can access Icons like this, for example:
Icons.AutoMirrored.TwoTone.ArrowForward
Icons.Filled.VisibilityOff

Use the Material 3 composable Icon that takes an imageVector to draw such an icon:
Icon(
    imageVector = Icons.Outlined.DirtyLens,
    contentDescription = TODO(),
)


Regarding your attempt to switch to Material 2 by simply changing the 3 to 2 in implementation(libs.androidx.material3) doesn't work because you would need an according entry in the version catalog for that. Simply middle-click on libs.androidx.material3 to jump to the version catalog to see for yourself. Its entry will look something like this:
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }

If you had an entry for Material 2 there (which you most likely do not and also won't need) it would look something like this:
androidx-material = { group = "androidx.compose.material", name = "material" }

Note that Material 2 dependencies do not use the number 2. They cannot be confused with Material 1 because there is no Material 1 library. Only when Material 3 was developed they added a number to the new libraries to distinguish them from the Material 2 libraries that did not have a number.
